# Display Validation Errors on Modal with Symfony 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

**EDIT:** I have a form template that I include in a modal box. It works perfectly when you click the button to open the modal.

```
<button href="{{ path('monteal_backend_company_add') }}" data-modal-id="add-company" class="primary add-company-launch">Add Company</button>


<div id="add-company" class="modal display-hidden">
    <div class="content pad-10">
        <a href="" class="modal-close float-right">
            <i class="material-icons md-18">close</i>
        </a>

        <h3 class="font-bold pad-top-15">Add Company</h3>
        <hr>

        {{ render(controller('MontealBundle:Admin/Backend/Company:new')) }}

    </div>
</div>
```

Inside of template I have..

```
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
    <p class="alert note-error">
        There are errors in your form. Please check the fields marked in red.
    </p>
{% endif %}

{{ form_errors(form) }}

<div class="sections pb30 pt10">
    <fieldset class="col span6 alert {% if form_errors(form.name) is not empty %}error{% endif %}">
        <label for="" class="input-required">
            <strong>Name <span class="highlight-red">*</span></strong>
        </label>
        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
        {% if not form.name.vars.valid %}
            <p class="mt10" style="color: #DC2B1B;">{{ form.name.vars.errors[0].message }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

As you can there is a validation script that already incorporated with the template.

The problem is when I submit the form, the validation messages didn't display in my modal box.

Here's my Ajax event.

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.withdropdown').dropdown();
            $('.add-company-launch').modal();

            $('#company-form').submit(function(e) {

                var formUrl = "{{ path('monteal_backend_company_ajax') }}";
                var formData = new FormData(this)

                $.ajax({
                    url: formUrl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  formData,
                     contentType: false,
                     cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        if(data['status'] === 'success'){
                            alert('success');
                        } else {
                            $('#add-company').html(data['html']);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                    }
                });

                e.preventDefault();
            });
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And here's my controller.

```
public function newAction() {

        $company = new Company();

        $form = $this->createForm(CompanyForm::class, $company);

        return $this->render('Admin/Backend/Company/new.html.twig', array(
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ));
    }

    public function ajaxAction(Request $request) {

        if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'You can access this only using Ajax!'), 400);
        }

        $company = new Company();
        $form = $this->createForm(CompanyForm::class, $company);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($company);
            $em->flush();

            return new JsonResponse(array(
                'status' => 'success'), 200
            );
        }

        $html = $this->renderView("Admin/Backend/Company/new.html.twig", array(
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ));

        $data = array('status' => 'error', 'html' => $html);

        return new JsonResponse($data, 400);
    }
```

Here's is my routing.

```
monteal_backend_company_add:
    path: /admin/company/add
    defaults: { _controller: MontealBundle:Admin/Backend/Company:new }

monteal_backend_company_ajax:
    path: /admin/company/ajax
    defaults: { _controller: MontealBundle:Admin/Backend/Company:ajax }
```

Can someone please explain why the validation messsages didn't display in modal/form.

Comment: Since you're returning response with HTTP 400 status your `error:` would get triggered with corresponding arguments. Put your error handling/showing code there.

Comment: I update my code above.